# Remote software Install on Windows 8 and above

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, remote, windows-8, installation

Back in Windows XP/7 I remember being shown how to remote software installs via .msi with AD. Can you still do that in Windows 2012/8 days or was that dropped/removed? I've not even seen it mentioned in any 2012 tutorials either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group Policy - it's still here, can deploy software via Software Publishing (.msi only), or logon scripts.

Also, in some cases [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) becomes really handy method to install software almost anywhere.

Comment: Please note that a lot of administrators avoid the GPO .msi software installs because of a long list of problems and exceptions with this method.